# Deployment Order - sharing rules and Users

Tags: deployment, administration

We have altogether 5Million+ records spread out on various objects, we have to deploy new set of sharing rules and migrate new set of users.

What is the best order of deployment?

Deploying sharing rules first and then users or vice versa?

Comment: are the user using existing profiles? are the sharing rules base on specific users / roles?

Comment: @Eric - We are using existing profiles and as well as new profiles. Sharing rules are based on specific roles.  Load Profiles - Load Data - Load Users --> this is our approach as per our analysis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update the sharing rules first, as they will take significantly longer to process up-front, and loading the records and users first will cause this up-front sharing change to take significantly longer. Add the new users next, and then load the users last.